# Python Unit Converter for Time using PyQt5 Module

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have made a GUI application using PyQt5 module for my Unit converter for Time(Meaning converts the units of Time like seconds to milliseconds, minutes to milliseconds, etc) using a QtDesigner. But the only problem I am facing is that I do not know where and how to input the function of my application to make it work as a unit converter for Time. Below is the full code of my GUI application:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_UnitConverter(object):
    def setupUi(self, UnitConverter):
        UnitConverter.setObjectName("UnitConverter")
        UnitConverter.resize(728, 601)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(UnitConverter)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.dropShadowFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.dropShadowFrame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
                                           "    background-color: rgb(44, 50, 86);\n"
                                           "    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);\n"
                                           "}")
        self.dropShadowFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.dropShadowFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.dropShadowFrame.setObjectName("dropShadowFrame")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 50, 311, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(79, 199, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 200, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(7)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {\n"
                                    "background-color: rgb(115, 199, 255);\n"
                                    "border: none;\n"
                                    "border-radius: 9px;\n"
                                    "}")
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 200, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(7)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {\n"
                                      "background-color: rgb(115, 199, 255);\n"
                                      "border: none;\n"
                                      "border-radius: 9px;\n"
                                      "}")
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.comboBox_1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.comboBox_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 200, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox_1.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_1.setStyleSheet("QComboBox {\n"
                                      "\n"
                                      "    background-color: rgb(44, 50, 86);\n"
                                      "    color: rgb(79, 199, 255);\n"
                                      "    border: none;\n"
                                      "    border-radius: 9px;\n"
                                      "    text -align: center;\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "")
        self.comboBox_1.setObjectName("comboBox_1")
        self.comboBox_1.addItem("Second[s]")
        self.comboBox_1.addItem("Millisecond[ms]")
        self.comboBox_1.addItem("Minute[m]")
        self.comboBox_1.addItem("Hour[h]")
        self.comboBox_1.addItem("Day[D]")
        self.comboBox_1.addItem("Year[y]")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 200, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_2.setStyleSheet("QComboBox {\n"
                                      "\n"
                                      "    background-color: rgb(44, 50, 86);\n"
                                      "    color: rgb(79, 199, 255);\n"
                                      "    border: none;\n"
                                      "    border-radius: 9px;\n"
                                      "    text -align: center;\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "")
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("Second[s]")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("Millisecond[ms]")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("Minute[m]")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("Hour[h]")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("Day[D]")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("Year[y]")
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.comboBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 450, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox_3.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_3.setStyleSheet("QComboBox {\n"
                                      "\n"
                                      "    background-color: rgb(44, 50, 86);\n"
                                      "    color: rgb(79, 199, 255);\n"
                                      "    border: none;\n"
                                      "    border-radius: 9px;\n"
                                      "    text -align: center;\n"
                                      "}\n"
                                      "")
        self.comboBox_3.setEditable(False)
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("TIME")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 170, 81, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(247, 19, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 170, 81, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(247, 19, 255);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.dropShadowFrame)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 390, 91, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(247, 19, 255);")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dropShadowFrame)
        UnitConverter.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(UnitConverter)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(UnitConverter)

    def retranslateUi(self, UnitConverter):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        UnitConverter.setWindowTitle(_translate("UnitConverter", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("UnitConverter",
                                      "<html><head/><body><p>MY <span style=\" font-weight:600;\">UNIT CONVERTER</span></p></body></html>"))

        self.label_2.setText(_translate("UnitConverter",
                                        "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">FROM:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("UnitConverter",
                                        "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">TO:</span></p><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("UnitConverter",
                                        "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\">TYPE:</span></p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    UnitConverter = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_UnitConverter()
    ui.setupUi(UnitConverter)
    UnitConverter.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you explain better what *unit converter for Time* means?

Comment: Its exactly what it states. Its a unit converter but focuses only on Time. Meaning every unit of time either from seconds to milliseconds, minutes to milliseconds, etc

Comment: You should point that out in your post since the phrase that I point out is very generic and can have many interpretations. Please improve your post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Post improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt uses a concept called "Signal/Slot mechanism".

Every Qt object ([QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html), which is inherited by *all* Qt widgets) is able to "emit" signals with a (possibly empty) amount of arguments, and that signal can be "registered" to *slots*, which are functions that will be called everytime that signal are emitted.<sup>[1]</sup>

A typical case is a button (normally, a [QPushButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html)), which has a [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal<sup>[2]</sup> that is emitted whenever the button is clicked, meaning that the mouse cursor is *over* the button *both* when the mouse button is pressed ***and*** then released.

Every Qt widget has different signals depending on its purpose.
For instance, the QLineEdit control has a `textChanged` (that is emitted whenever the text is changed, *even* programmatically) and `textEdited` (which is only emitted when the user actually types something in it).
A QComboBox has the `currentIndexChanged` signal, emitted whenever the current item is changed (for instance, opening the popup and selecting a *different* item, or by using the mouse wheel over it).

In the following code, I'll be connecting to "slots" (in this case, simple python functions) by completely ignoring the arguments of the related signals, but there are cases for which those arguments are actually needed.

The idea is that whenever the user types something in any of the line edit fields, the related function tries to convert the typed value to a numeric one, and then, based on the current content of the comboboxes will do the proper conversion.

Consider that:

1. QLineEdit is not a suggested control for numeric input. A QSpinBox (for integers, otherwise a QDoubleSpinBox for floating points) is more suited for such situations; alternatively, setting a QIntValidator or QDoubleValidator on the line edit is possible.
2. Using [`combobox.addItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItem) allows setting *user data* for each item along with the visible label; I'm using that "hidden" data by means of `currentData()` for multiplicators that are used for the conversion; this also means that you should *remove* any existing item for those comboboxes from the UI in Designer.
3. Editing files generated by `pyuic` is considered bad practice (for a lot of reasons); I strongly suggest you to carefully read the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), generate again the files from the UI and *never* touch them again (unless by overwriting with pyuic): those files should always be used as *imports* only. In the following code I'm assuming you've updated your UI (by removing the items in the first two combos) and converted them again to a file named `unitConverterUi.py`, which will **NOT** be the actual script you'll be running.
4. Using fixed geometries (manually positioning and resizing widgets) is rarely a good idea. Remember that what you see on your screen is almost always **never** what others will see on theirs. Read more about [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and how to [use them in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). User interfaces should be able to *adapt* to the screen and system settings of the user (what is called "responsive design" in modern website design).

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from unitConverterUi import Ui_UnitConverter

Conversions = (
    ('Second[s]', 1), 
    ('Millisecond[ms]', .001), 
    ('Minute[m]', 60), 
    ('Hour[h]', 3600), 
    ('Day[d]', 86400), 
    ('Year[y]', 31536000)
)

class UnitConverter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_UnitConverter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        for label, multi in Conversions:
            self.comboBox_1.addItem(label, multi)
            self.comboBox_2.addItem(label, multi)

        self.lineEdit.textEdited.connect(self.convertTo)
        self.lineEdit_2.textEdited.connect(self.convertFrom)
        self.comboBox_1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboChanged)
        self.comboBox_2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboChanged)

        self.lastEdited = self.lineEdit

    def convertTo(self):
        try:
            value = int(self.lineEdit.text())
        except ValueError:
            return
        self.lastEdited = self.lineEdit
        seconds = value * self.comboBox_1.currentData()
        result = str(seconds / self.comboBox_2.currentData())
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(result.rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))

    def convertFrom(self):
        try:
            value = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        except ValueError:
            return
        self.lastEdited = self.lineEdit_2
        seconds = value * self.comboBox_2.currentData()
        result = str(seconds / self.comboBox_1.currentData())
        self.lineEdit.setText(result.rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))

    def comboChanged(self):
        if self.lastEdited == self.lineEdit:
            self.convertTo()
        else:
            self.convertFrom()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    converter = UnitConverter()
    converter.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<sup>[1]</sup> Connecting a signal to a slot isn't exclusive: you can connect more "slots" to a signal; note that you can even connect the same signal to the same slot more than once, the result is that whenever that signal is emitted, *every* connected slot will be called, even if it's the same: if you connect a signal to the same function twice, that function will be called twice.
<sup>[2]</sup> The `clicked` signal has a default "checked" argument, which is always `False` for uncheckable buttons; remember that, as it's common to connect to a function that accepts an arguments and beginners always struggle with that because they don't understand from where that boolean value comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will definitely apply this knowledge and see what happens. Thanks again

Comment: I applied your code and it works perfectly well with my GUI application. Now I just need to reformat my code for my GUI application and rewrite it as the QtDesigner is a mess to your code when you take too much time editing in the Designer. I want to Thank you again

Comment: @MrWannabe if you still have the ui you used for your question, you only need to remove all items in the first two combo boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I just finally had the time to post this. First of all, Thanks to the help of @musicamante. I was able to make his code work with my GUI and also did some adjustments to the structure and content of the code.
Note how I made the code from musicamante to work with the GUI. I also reworked my GUI code to make it more neat and tidy. One thing I learned from using PyQt5 is that if you are struggling with positioning the UI, I would recommend you use a layout for your UI. In this case I used a QGridLayout. This will help positioning it and also auto adjust the positioning and sizing of the UI based on the screen size. The following shows the code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

# Note that these conversions are all in seconds.
# These conversions are the ones which will be used in adding the QComboBox
# contents as well as the values which will be used in the conversion calculations
Conversions = (
    ('Second', 1),
    ('Millisecond', .001),
    ('Microsecond', .000001),
    ('Nanosecond', .000000001),
    ('Picosecond', .000000000001),
    ('Minute', 60),
    ('Hour', 3600),
    ('Day', 86400),
    ('Week', 604800),
    ('Month', 2629800),
    ('Year(calendar)', 31536000),
    ('Year(tropical)', 31556930),
    ('Year(sidereal)', 31558150)
)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):  # This is the main function of the class Window
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "Unit Converter"  # The title which will appear in the main window
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 500
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 400
        self.iconName = "time.png"  # Added a png file for the icon picture of my Window

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.iconName))  # A method to display the icon picture in the Window
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)  # Sets Geometry of application
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 50, 86);")  # Sets background color of application
        self.move(500, 150)

        self.initUI()  # Calls the function initUI
        self.show()  # Shows the application on screen when run

        # for method which uses the Conversions array content to be added to both
        # the QComboBoxes combo and combo2
        for label, multi in Conversions:
            self.combo.addItem(label, multi)
            self.combo2.addItem(label, multi)

        # Calls the functions convertTo and convertFrom whenever a text is edited inside both QLineEdits e1 and e2
        self.e1.textEdited.connect(self.convertTo)
        self.e2.textEdited.connect(self.convertFrom)
        # Calls function comboChanged whenever both combo or combo2 current index is changed
        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboChanged)
        self.combo2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboChanged)

        self.lastEdited = self.e1

    # This is a function which adds attributes for the application
    # It is where all the attributes are defined as well
    # It is where the UI are added as well to the application
    def initUI(self):

        gbox = QGridLayout()  # variable for layout of the application
        self.setLayout(gbox)   # Sets the layout of the application

        self.combo = QComboBox()    # QComboBox called combo which will store all the units of time
        self.combo.setStyleSheet("QComboBox {\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "    background-color: rgb(44, 50, 86);\n"
                                 "    color: rgb(79, 199, 255);\n"
                                 "    border: none;\n"
                                 "    border-radius: 9px;\n"
                                 "    text -align: center;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "")

        self.combo2 = QComboBox()  # QComboBox called combo2 which will store all the units of time
        self.combo2.setStyleSheet("QComboBox {\n"
                                  "\n"
                                  "    background-color: rgb(44, 50, 86);\n"
                                  "    color: rgb(79, 199, 255);\n"
                                  "    border: none;\n"
                                  "    border-radius: 9px;\n"
                                  "    text -align: center;\n"
                                  "}\n"
                                  "")

        self.e1 = QLineEdit()   # QLineEdit e1 is where the values will be entered
        self.e1.setPlaceholderText("Enter Value")   # Provided a place holder for better understanding
        self.e1.setMinimumWidth(200)    # Sets the minimum width of the QLineEdit
        self.e1.setValidator(QDoubleValidator())    # Sets the values acceptable to input as floating points
        self.e1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)    # Aligns text at center when typed
        self.e1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 10))   # Sets font and font size of text
        self.e1.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {\n"   # Provides edits to how the QLineEdit will look
                              "background-color: rgb(115, 199, 255);\n"
                              "border: none;\n"
                              "border-radius: 9px;\n"
                              "}")

        self.e2 = QLineEdit()
        self.e2.setMinimumWidth(200)
        self.e2.setValidator(QDoubleValidator())
        self.e2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.e2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 10))
        self.e2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {\n"
                              "background-color: rgb(115, 199, 255);\n"
                              "border: none;\n"
                              "border-radius: 9px;\n"
                              "}")

        self.label = QLabel("My UNIT CONVERTER")    # QLabel label to act as a title of the application
        myFont = QtGui.QFont()
        myFont.setBold(True)
        self.label.setFont(myFont)
        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Segoe UI", 15))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(247, 19, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.l1 = QLabel("From: ")      # QLabel l1 to act as an indicator for the From conversion
        self.l1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Segoe UI", 10))
        self.l1.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(247, 19, 255);")
        self.l1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.l2 = QLabel("To: ")    # QLabel l2 to act as an indicator for the To conversion
        self.l2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Segoe UI", 10))
        self.l2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(247, 19, 255);")
        self.l2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.l3 = QLabel("UNIT OF TIME")    # QLabel l3 to provide understanding what unit the application converts
        self.l3.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Segoe UI", 10))
        self.l3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(247, 19, 255);")
        self.l3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Below shows the added widgets which will appear in the application
        # all the added widgets are already created and customized above
        # the numbers shown at the end sets their location in the application
        # since we are using QGridLayout, this method is applicable
        gbox.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        gbox.addWidget(self.l1, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        gbox.addWidget(self.combo, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        gbox.addWidget(self.e1, 2, 3)
        gbox.addWidget(self.l2, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        gbox.addWidget(self.combo2, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        gbox.addWidget(self.e2, 4, 3)
        gbox.addWidget(self.l3, 6, 0, 1, 4)

    # Below are the functions which will be used to set the calculation
    # of the conversion process when the program is run

    # A function for the e1 QLineEdit which acts whenever a float is typed
    # It works for the "To" conversions
    # Makes calculations for e1 and displays result in e2 using combo and combo2 current data
    def convertTo(self):
        try:
            value = float(self.e1.text())
        except ValueError:
            return
        self.lastEdited = self.e1
        seconds = value * self.combo.currentData()
        result = str(seconds / self.combo2.currentData())
        self.e2.setText(result.rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))

    # A function for the e2 QLineEdit which acts whenever a float is typed
    # It works for the "From" conversions
    # It makes the calculations for e2 using combo and combo2 currentData and display result in e1
    def convertFrom(self):
        try:
            value = float(self.e2.text())
        except ValueError:
            return
        self.lastEdited = self.e2
        seconds = value * self.combo2.currentData()
        result = str(seconds / self.combo.currentData())
        self.e1.setText(result.rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))

    # This is a function for both the QLineEdits indicating whenever
    # a value is entered or edited, it will call the above functions to work
    def comboChanged(self):
        if self.lastEdited == self.e1:
            self.convertTo()
        else:
            self.convertFrom()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    App.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))   # This just sets the style of the application when run
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

If you want to see how it looks when run, I also attached a picture showing the application. And yes all units added in the code works. I tested them all and they work. This would not be possible without the help of the code from @musicamante so credits to him. This code is for the community so I'll just post it here.

[image: Picture of application when run]